# Does spring cloud config support centralizing certificates?

Tags: spring-cloud-config

Can I store keystore files in git repo and access it via Spring cloud config server? or does it support only property files?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Config Server does support loading static files through a URL:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_serving_plain_text

After retrieving the file, the key store file can be loaded programmatically: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-cryptography/keystore.html#loading-the-keystore

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it does. 
Store keystore file in git repo and access it via /{name}/{profile}/{label}/{path}. 
Reference /{name}/{profile}/{label}/{path}